# Normality test of one column using chi-square test in python

Tags: python

I have a df with two columns, one is date and another one is the CO2 Concentration by burning fossil fuels.
I was wondering to see how I can test the normality of a CO2 data over time using chi square test.

I tried code below, but it did not work.

```py
from scipy import stats
stats.chisquare(df_br["CO2"])
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the null/nan values first before computing the chisquare
more information on that function can be found [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare
output = chisquare(df['CO2'].dropna())
```

however as mentioned in the comments you are after the P-VALUE, which would require the following [method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html)

```
chi2, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(df['CO2'].dropna())
```

Comment: I tried this one. It is basically the same as what I wrote in the question. It does not give me any result! Output is: Power_divergenceResult(statistic=nan, pvalue=nan)

Comment: Thanks. There is one thing that I need to mention. There are Null data in the CO2 column

Comment: it gave me this reult: Power_divergenceResult(statistic=4962714.655512799, pvalue=0.0)                 I am not sure it is a correct thing and how I am going to interpret it!

Comment: I answered the question correctly, as you mentioned you wanted to use chi square test, but perhaps you are after the P value, which would require you to use this method.
chi2, p, dof, expected = chi2_contingency(df['CO2'].dropna())


https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html